# 2 div's position not working on firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, position

I have problem with my website,I have content container, where I have photos on left and product desc on right side. On Chrome it's working good, but on Mozilla FF no. I don't have idea what may be wrong. Anybody can help me ?

http://jsfiddle.net/PPjQj/

```
                <div class="product-photos">
                    <img src="images/product.png" class="product" alt="product">
                    <img src="images/product-min.png" alt="product-min"/>
                    <img src="images/product-min.png" alt="product-min" style="margin-left: 26px;"/>
                    <img src="images/product-min.png" alt="product-min" style="float:right;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="about-prod">
                    <div class="product-info">
                    <span class="title"> Informacje: </span>
                        <p class="info-details">Producent: <span class="info-details">KUBOLEK</span><br>
                        Kod produktu: <span class="info-details">KUB/123/OL/3/K</span><br>
                        Dostępność towaru: <span class="info-details dost">dostępny</span></p>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display:inline-block; change like this :

```
 .product-photos{
    width: 319px;
    height: 315px;
    margin-left: 212px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 85px;
     }
```